# winform .net best way if you want to display images in a datagridview

Tags: winforms, datagridview, picturebox

net webdeveloper and usually don't make any win32 apps. but now i have to. i have a list with about 2000 entries.
each entry should be displayed as, a label with textbox another label and picture. i have made this with a flowlayoutpanel and i did a foreach on the entries to make a panel for each entry with the label, textbox, label and a picturebox.

now i have rendering issues when it comes above 1000 entries.
so i have read that i should use a listview or datagridview.

now i have a datagridview like this:

```
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
dgv.AutoSize = true;
dgv.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;

System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Code", typeof(string));
dc1.ReadOnly = true;
dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Quantity", typeof(int)));
DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("Price", typeof(string));
dc3.ReadOnly = true;
dt.Columns.Add(dc3);
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Image", typeof(Bitmap)));

foreach (Product pd in products)
{
      DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
      dr["Code"] = pd.ProductCode;
      dr["Quantity"] = pd.ProductQuantity;
      dr["Price"] = "€ " + String.Format("{0:0,00}", pd.ProductResalePrice.ToString());

      dr["Image"] = BitmapFromWeb(pd.ProductImage);
      dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}

dt.AcceptChanges();
dgv.RowTemplate.Height = 50;
dgv.DataSource = dt;
```

but the thing is that a bitmap on a datagridview is really slow! the picturebox option and panels which i had before where much faster. how do i resolve this?

the second question is: which event do i need when i want to track the changes made in the 2nd column?

ow one thing: the images are online available so the 'pd.ProductImage' is an url

```
    private static Bitmap BitmapFromWeb(string URL)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
            myRequest.Method = "GET";
            HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
            System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(myResponse.GetResponseStream());
            myResponse.Close();

            return bmp;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null; // if for some reason we couldn't get to image, we return null
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the image load asyncrhonously then force a refresh of the cell. You can put your foreach code into a call to the ThreadPool, something like...

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
{
 foreach (DataRow row in dt)
 {
  row["Image"] = BitmapFromWeb(Products[row["Code"]].ProductImage);
  //maybe a call to invalidate here, remember to do Control.Invoke(...)
 }
}
```

---

Edit: here is a sample code that I tested inside the Form constructor...

```
        DataTable t= new DataTable();
        t.Columns.Add("id");
        t.Columns.Add("uri");
        t.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Img",typeof(Bitmap)));

        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(50, 15);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
        {
            g.DrawString("Loading...", this.Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 0f,0f);
        }

        t.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", "http://farm1.static.flickr.com/88/377522544_c4774f15cc_s.jpg", b });
        t.Rows.Add(new object[] { "2", "http://farm1.static.flickr.com/175/377522405_2c505def99_s.jpg", b });
        t.Rows.Add(new object[] { "3", "http://farm1.static.flickr.com/185/377524902_72f82e2db9_s.jpg", b });
        t.Rows.Add(new object[] { "4", "http://farm1.static.flickr.com/136/377524944_d011abf786_s.jpg", b });
        t.Rows.Add(new object[] { "5", "http://farm1.static.flickr.com/137/377528675_d3b9d541fb_s.jpg", b });
        dataGridView1.DataSource = t;
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in t.Rows)
            {
                HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(row["uri"].ToString());
                myRequest.Method = "GET";
                HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
                System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(myResponse.GetResponseStream());
                myResponse.Close();

                row["Img"] = bmp;
            }
        });

        dataGridView1.CellEndEdit += dataGridView1_CellEndEdit;
```

.... and in the cell end edit code:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string value = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["uri"].Value.ToString();
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
        {
                HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(value);
                myRequest.Method = "GET";
                HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
                System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(myResponse.GetResponseStream());
                myResponse.Close();
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Img"].Value=bmp;
        });
    }
```

Comment: thanks jmservera, but i am a noob when it comes to win32 coding. what do you mean with the control.invoke?
and do you know how to track the changes in the 2nd column textbox

Comment: hello jmservera, this is a lot faster, but it shows almost on every row the same image. i am new to threading... sorry

Comment: then review what are you sending to your bitmapfromweb code, I did not test the code I only wrote it as a kind of C# pseudocode.

Answer (score 1):

```
// table is DataTable object declared as member in my form class
table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", typeof(System.Drawing.Bitmap)));

dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

Comment: Lol, you answered a thread from dec 2009! with a sync solution instead of async