# Get a image in data gridview to picturebox in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, picturebox

I need to get an image in data gridview to picturebox in c#

This is my datagridview cord.

```
if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
{

    DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView3.Rows[e.RowIndex];

    e_id.Text = row.Cells["emp_id"].Value.ToString();
    e_Fname.Text = row.Cells["emp_Fname"].Value.ToString();
    e_Lname.Text = row.Cells["emp_Lname"].Value.ToString();

}
```

I need to click a row in datagridview then load image in picturebox.

Comment: Where is your image's field ? `emp_Fname` or `emp_Lname` ?

Answer (score 5):

Surprisingly but NOBODY above provided the correct answer.
The request above was: **"I need to click a row in datagridview then load image in picturebox."**

*Here is the correct way in C# or just use CType to cast to byte array for VB:*

```
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])grdProducts.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value);
 picProduct.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

MikeB443 [kd2cmo][image]

Answer (score 1):

### Here is my solution. It works correctly for me to retrieve an image from DataGridView to load in PictureBox.

**Form Event:**

```
 Private con As New SqlConnection("YourConnectionString")
    Private com As SqlCommand
Private Sub DGV_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGV.CellClick
        con.Open()
        com = New SqlCommand("SELECT MyPhoto FROM tbGalary WHERE ID=" & DGV.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value, con)
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream(CType(com.ExecuteScalar, Byte()))
        txtPicture.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
        txtPicture.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        com.Dispose()
        con.Close()
End Sub
```

**SQL Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbGalary](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MyPhoto] [image] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

**SQL Insert image:**

```
INSERT INTO tbGalary VALUES('1','D:\image1.jpg')
INSERT INTO tbGalary VALUES('2','D:\image2.jpg')
INSERT INTO tbGalary VALUES('3','D:\image3.jpg')
INSERT INTO tbGalary VALUES('4','D:\image4.jpg')
INSERT INTO tbGalary VALUES('5','D:\image5.jpg')
```

**Result**

Video link: [Retrieve an image in DataGridView load to PictureBox in VB.NET](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5QCjtAYnGE&feature=youtu.be)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
pictureBox1.Image = (Image)dataGridView3.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value;
```

Use your indexes here according to your column and the row.

Comment: thank you. but i got this error.


Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.Drawing.Image'.

Comment: @Shaaji how are you saving the image into the `gridview`? show the code

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an ImageList to store the images, what I do in this case is store the index of the image in the Tag property of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
Image newImage = (Image)row[8].Value;
pictureBox1.Image = newImage;
```

**or**

```
Image newImage = (Image)dgvDisplayTiles.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value;
pictureBox1.Image = newImage;
```

row[8].Value will be according to your Datagridview because I am using Superdatagrid view that's why I wrote row[8].Value.

Answer (score -1):

I know that it already late but I still really want to share my solution.

on the properties of datagrid. You will found CellClick.

```
 private void sampleGrid_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
            {
               string picpath = @"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\FolderOfYourImages\";
               //"emp_Lname" or the column index that you want to use               
               picpath = picpath + sampleGrid["emp_Lname", grdTrans.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value.toString() + ".jpg"
               picbox.ImageLocation = picpath;
            }
```

When you will click the datagrid. It will change the image in picture box. For my sample, I choose the LastName to be the image name. But It will be up to you it will be just a simple concatenation. And Lastly, Just make sure that the image is existing in your path.

Hope this will still help :) Happy Coding.

Comment: Based on what i saw on his code the image is in byte format.

Comment: why down vote?? it just state that "I need to click a row in datagridview then load image in picturebox.". It does not mention that it is in byte.