# Change DataGridView's cell image based on a property in DataGridView's DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have a `DataTable` that contains the following columns:

1. Id
2. ImageIndex
3. Source
4. Destination

On my form's load event I would like to populate my `DataGridView` with my `DataTable`. But I would also like to have an image column that shows a different image based on the value of *ImageIndex* on my `DataTable`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

First step is to add the images in your Resources.resx file under properties folder. Then add a DataGridViewImageColumn in your DataGridView.

Lastly use this snippet on your databound event of your gridview.

```
for (int row = 0; row <= [YourDataGridViewName].Rows.Count - 1; row++)
 {
    if(gvFiles.Rows[row].Cells["Index of the imageindexcolumn"]).Value = 1)
        {
            (DataGridViewImageCell)gvFiles.Rows[row].Cells["Index of the imagecolumn"]).Value = Properties.Resources.Picture1
        } 
    else if (gvFiles.Rows[row].Cells["Index of the imageindexcolumn"]).Value = 2)
        {
            (DataGridViewImageCell)gvFiles.Rows[row].Cells["Index of the imagecolumn"]).Value = Properties.Resources.Picture2
        } 
}
```

Comment: This will work fine if the image has been imported into Resources.resx.  My guess is though that the image might come from a URL stored in the database.  If this is the case, please have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759772/how-to-show-image-from-url-in-datagridview-cell